# How to offset a column only on desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not new to the bootstrap 3 grid system, but previously only worked with stacked columns on mobile.

Today I need a grid with a single column on mobile, taking the full width (no scrollbars). On larger devices, the column should be centered (offsetted ?) while an appropriate width is maintained.

How can I do that ?

So far I have tried the following :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
... content ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is looking fine on desktop and mobile, but then I realized I have scrollbars on mobile.

Could it be surrounding html (not shown here) ? Or is it related to this code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing that would create scrollbars on mobile is the `..content...`, so you to show what the content is for us to repro the issue.

Comment: This was in fact caused by a css applied earlier on a div

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions.

The first solution sets the max-width of your column to a fixed number of pixels (in this case 650px);

The second solution set the max-width of the column to a certain percentage of the window until you reach a breakpoint and it sets it to 100%.

Solution 1 (run it full screen and change the window width to see it in action):

```css
.constrain {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="constrain">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: coral;">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution 2 (run it full screen and change the window width to see it in action):

```css
.constrain {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .constrain {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="constrain">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: coral;">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```